Confused about returning std::unique_ptr
So say I have a tree structure, with a node defined like:
struct Node
{
    byte key_part;
    unique_ptr<Node> left, right, middle;
    TValue value;
};
unique_ptr<Node> root;

The semantics here are correct, I absolutely don't want others to get a hold of my node itself. It is uniquely held by my tree.
However, I want to add an internal helper function to search the tree based on internal semantics and return a ...something? to the node structure. This is a private function, only used internally to either insert a node and fill it in with data from outside, delete a node or return the value field (not the node itself) outside. The node in no way leaks outside.
So how do I write the function? I can't return unique_ptr<Node> from it, right? Or move semantics will kick in. I could return a pointer, but that seems to break the system, plus it leads to aliasing issues. A reference is similar, but it prevents me from using nullptr to mark no result found. In essence, what would the return type of this be:
/* return type here */ search(const span<byte>& key)
{
    auto node = /* recursive search here, etc */;
    return /* what do I put here, given I have a unique_ptr<Node> reference? */;
}


"I could return a pointer, but that seems to break the system"  Can you elaborate?  From any object, you may produce a pointer to that object.  What would doing so break?

Note: Raw pointers are perfectly acceptable in implementing data structures like trees and linked lists. Just make sure your struct/class obeys the rule of 3/5/0.

Am I misunderstanding aliasing? Isn't that a big no-no when avoidable?

You may return a std::optional, which stores either a reference or "nothing". Advantage over a raw pointer would be that it clearly expresses intent.

What clearly expressed intent is that? A reference to some memory somewhere? An unique_ptr<T> clearly expresses intent, that it's an owned object. Besides I'm not asking about how to use optional.

Aliasing is an issue when you have several pointers, which the compiler thinks might legally overlap (and therefore can't cache loads through), but which really don't overlap. Returning a raw or smart pointer doesn't change this at all.

@Blindy I can't imagine that this function could avoid aliasing if (as you describe) you need to return something that in some way refers to your node.  That said, I also wouldn't consider it a big no-no to use a pointer in this context.  You don't seem to intend to do anything that would be harmed by aliasing.

@Blindy "Am I misunderstanding aliasing?" -- Well, the example in that answer shows a case where the compiler cannot optimize because it has to assume that the value pointer might point into the data structure at hand (array, in that answer). In your case, the returned pointer would definitely point into the data structure at hand (your tree), so those optimizations are off the table from the start. In a sense, you want the "aliasing issues".

I could return a pointer... Yes, that is what you should return.  ...but that seems to break the system...  In what way? Could you provide code that demonstrates how the system was broken.  ...plus it leads to aliasing issues. Could you provide code demonstrating the aliasing issues that it lead to.


However, I want to add an internal helper function to search the tree based on internal semantics and return a ...something?

Just return a raw pointer. Raw pointers are the canonical representation of a non-owning nullable reference, which is exactly what you want.
For reassurance, see the C++ Core Guidelines on this subject.

I could return a pointer, but that seems to break the system, plus it leads to aliasing issues.

It doesn't break anything.
It doesn't cause aliasing issues either - these arise when you have:

two or more pointers (to the same or pointer-interconvertible types)
which the compiler has to assume may overlap (ie, it can't prove they will never overlap)
where you write through one, and read through the other
so the compiler has to assume the write could have changed the value it should read, so cannot cache that read
but you know the pointers really will never overlap and would prefer the optimizer to cache that read

The classic example of this is the distinction between memcpy (which assumes non-overlapping ranges) and memmove (which has to take extra precautions to deal with possibly-overlapping ranges).
Whether you use a raw pointer or a smart one doesn't affect that at all.

"but you know the pointers really will never overlap and would prefer the optimizer to cache that read", could you expand on that, please? The pointer I'd return from the search function would absolutely overlap (in fact, be identical) to the unique_ptr held by its parent node

No, the aliasing problem isn't two pointers to the same object. That is an alias, but not a problem. The problem arises when a function has two pointers which it has to assume may be aliases, and this disables some optimization you know (but can't tell the compiler without the restrict keyword) could safely be enabled.

Perhaps I didn't explain it well enough, though I thought I did. Your answer seems to be emphasizing the difference between possibly overlapping and non-overlapping ranges, as well as between raw pointers and smart pointers. There is no such distinction in the code I'm talking about, the node is held both by a smart pointer (as seen in the code in my question) and (possibly, as per your suggestion) by a raw pointer when returned by my search function. The two pointers that exist at the same time are absolutely aliased to the same object.

@Blindy: Yes, you have aliasing, but you do not have a problem.  Aliasing problem does not mean "aliasing is a problem", it's a category of problems that can arise in relation to aliasing

People are too scared of raw pointers.  They're actually perfect when you don't need to concern yourself with the lifetime of the pointed to object.

OK, I see, thank you. @MarkRansom, that is a crazy statement to make. The fewer pointers I see in the wild the better.

@Blindy That's a religious view, not an objective one. The main problems that occur with pointers are due to inappropriate usage e.g. insufficient care managing lifetime of a pointed-to object (destroying it multiple times, use after destruction, not destroying it, etc). Too many programmers blame pointers for the problems instead of their own lack of due care. Smart pointers, like unique_ptr, make it easier to apply needed due care, but there is still a place for careful use of pointers. Your scenario is such a case, so the "avoid pointer" mantra causes more problems than it solves.

@Useless for the record your link explicitly lists your suggestion as, and I quote, "Example, bad; Returning a (raw) pointer imposes a lifetime management uncertainty on the caller; that is, who deletes the pointed-to object?"

You missed the last line of the paragraph you're referring to: "Note This rule applies to factory functions." Since we're not discussing factory functions, or any public interface, this is obviously not relevant.
